# How can I get Infinit Reflections on Cylces

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, mirror, glass, reflection

I have this circular room with mirrors instead of walls, but when I go to the render tab, at some point it gets black, how can I make the mirror material have limitless reflections?

I'm using the latest version of blender 2.82, an my mirror material its a *Principled BSDF* full metallic no roughness.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: [How to take a ScreenShot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/windows.html)

Comment: U save my life!, thank u

Answer (score 2):

You need to increase the number of Light Bounces.
It cannot be infinite, but it doesn't need to be.

- head to *Render Tab > Light Paths > Max Bounces*
- adjust both the *Glossy* value and the *Total* value to your liking
- to look infinite, the latest reflection needs to be of 1px size

*How many Suzannes do you see...?*

[image]